# How to not repeat child but bind parent with ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a structure like this:

`Items` is an array of objects and `itemName` is different for each repetition also in an array. The following structure works with the Items array but how can I change the `itemName` to be different for each repetition?

```
<div ng-repeat="Item in Items">
    <div>{{itemName}}</div>
    <ul ng-repeat="it in Item">
        <li>
            {{it.title}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the data object is like follows:

`Items = [
       [{ title="title11"},{ title="title12"},{ title="title13"},{     title="title14"}],
        [{ title="title21"},{ title="title22"},{ title="title23"},{ title="title24"}]
    ];`

itemname is a simple array with just names:

`itemName = ["name1", "name2"];`

the name has the header for each component and titles are displayed in li

Comment: What do you want to do? Repeat li with keeping ng-repeat with ul?

Comment: what is the structure of your Items (array of objects) and where you have defined itemName???

Comment: @nikhil.agw I want to repeat both div and ul but the corresponding name is what changes with every repeat

Comment: @shreya added the structure in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code

```
<div>{{itemName}}</div>
```

with

```
<div>{{itemName[$index]}}</div>
```